# How to get the tick boxes to change value in the second window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter

I got example code were there are two windows and in the second one there's a tick box that doesn't change value when it is ticked. How can I fix this? I tried returning the value of the tickbox however that failed as well.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def open_custom_gui():
    custom_gui()

b = Button(root,command=open_custom_gui)
b.grid(row=1,column=0)

def custom_gui():
    def getinfo():
        print(var1.get())

    custom= Tk()
    var1 = IntVar()
    tickbox_1 = Checkbutton(custom,text='TEST',variable=var1,)
    tickbox_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    b = Button(custom,command=getinfo)
    b.grid(row=1,column=0)

    custom.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has something to do with calling `Tk()` twice. You can fix that by explicitly creating a second `Toplevel` window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def open_custom_gui():
    custom_gui()

b = Button(root, command=open_custom_gui)
b.grid(row=1, column=0)

def custom_gui():
    def getinfo():
        print(var1.get())

    custom = Toplevel()  # CHANGE THIS (don't call Tk() again)
    var1 = IntVar()
    tickbox_1 = Checkbutton(custom, text='TEST', variable=var1)
    tickbox_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    b = Button(custom, command=getinfo)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

    custom.mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively you can also fix it by specifying the second `Tk` instance when you create the `IntVar` tkinter variable:

```
def custom_gui():
    def getinfo():
        print(var1.get())

    custom = Tk()
    var1 = IntVar(master=custom)  # ADD a "master" keyword argument
    tickbox_1 = Checkbutton(custom, text='TEST', variable=var1)
    tickbox_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    b = Button(custom, command=getinfo)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

    custom.mainloop()
```

However I would suggest using the first approach because the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) says the following (about adding the argument to the `IntVar` constructor):

> The constructor argument is only relevant if you’re running Tkinter with
>   multiple Tk instances (which you shouldn’t do, unless you really know what
>   you’re doing).

Comment: Thank you so much !